# keyword not popping up when onfocused input field

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I am new to angular/ionic4.i have created the input field when it is focused the keyboard is supposed to be popup but it is popping up only for android only when u again tap in the input field even after the field is focused but  for ios is not popping up at all

```html
<ion-input type="input" placeholder="Enter your first name" [readonly]="isReadOnly" 
name="profile" [value]="firstName" #nameCtrl="ngModel" ngModel pattern="[A-Za-z]+" 
minlength="3" maxlength="20" [(ngModel)]="firstName" #name no-padding>
</ion-input>
```

and I have tried implementing Cordova keyboard plugin but it doesn't work.

Comment: because its `readonly` input tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to delete

[readonly]="isReadOnly"